# Yeoman generated Angular application not loading injected dependencies

Tags: angularjs, bower, yeoman, code-injection, ng-dialog

Probably a newbie's question, but I need to add the ngDialog module to angular.
I noticed that after installing with bower Yeoman doesn't automatically update files, so I added

```
<script src="bower_components/ngDialog/js/ngDialog.js"></script>
```

to index.html.

I went ahead and added `'ngDialog'` to the main module dependencies, like this

```
angular.module('sigaApp', ['ngDialog'])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function () {
    this.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
  });
```

I also added `$scope` and `'ngDialog'` to my controller, like this

```
angular.module('sigaApp')
    .controller('myNewCtrl', ['$scope', 'ngDialog',
        function ($scope, ngDialog) {
            $scope.open = function () {
                ngDialog.open({ template: 'templateId' });
            };
        }
    ]
);
```

That's ALL I did. Grunt refreshes the page with no error, and the page console shows no error, but the page shows **nothing**, and I have just no idea why.

Should it load the dependencies automatically, and I shouldn't be adding these injections manually?
Is there another standard way to add the dependencies?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you actually call `$scope.open()`? Is `templateId` a template that exists? https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog#template-string --- also, as you're using grunt, you should imho refer to an HTML file `template: 'template.html'` that contains the template

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question: Removed the module and installed with `bower install ng-dialog --save` adding **--save** to the command line.

What the **--save** parameter does, actually is that it "Save installed packages into the project's bower.json dependencies" (quoting bower help) and as far as I'm aware of, there's where Yeoman takes the dependencies from to update index.html.